# Point in Matrix coordinates

Tags: android, events, view, matrix, touch-event

Is it possible to check if a point is contained in a Matrix coordinates? I have the original Matrix used to draw a View and want to know if the onTouch event coordinates are included in its coordinates.
Thanks

---

Ok, I should explain better. 
I have a custom View MyView. In its constructor i pass the matrix to draw the view. The onDraw method is:

```
@Override   
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {  
         super.onDraw(canvas);
         canvas.drawBitmap(this.baseBitmap, this.matrix, null); 
}
```

In the onTouch method i can get the touched point with `event.getX()` and `event.getY()` and using these, i need to check if the touched point is inside MyView.

Hope it's clear now :)

Comment: hi vilandra you can get the x and y co-ordinates as `event.getX(); and event.getY();` and then you can compare it with ur matrix values

Comment: @Dinash: I don't know how to get exactly matrix values (I need, for example, edges)

Comment: you mean edges of the display screen

Comment: that's fine vilandra where did you place that view... k you r placing it in the position mentioned in matrix... Will u be able to access the values of the matrix...

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code to calculate the (x4,y4) coordinates of a matrix.

```
float[] matrixValues = new float[9];
matrix.getValues(matrixValues);
view.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight() * matrixValues [0]; 
view.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWeight() * matrixValues [0];
```

Because of the layer management, perapse you have to use the following methode to check the ImageView coordinates :

```
yourImageView.getTop()
yourImageView.getBottom()
yourImageView.getRight()
yourImageView.getLeft()
```

e.g.

```
float[] m = new float[9];
matrix.getValues(m);
int layoutHeight = view.getBottom() - view.getTop();
float maxMatrixBottomPosition = - ((view.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight() * m[0]) - layoutHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float[] values = new float[9];
matrix.getValues(values);
globalX = values[2];
globalY = values[5];
```

here globalx and globaly will give the x and y co-ordinates of the your view and then compare it with the event.getX and event.getY values

Comment: I tried it yet in this way: 
`code`
float[] values = new float[9];
matrix.getValues(values);
globalX = values[2];
globalY = values[5];
width = values[0]*baseBitmap.getWidth();
height = values[4]*baseBitmap.getHeight();
`code`
And then, drew points in that coordinates to see where they are:
`code` 
canvas.drawPoint(globalX, globalY, paint);
canvas.drawPoint(globalX+width, globalY+height, paint); 
`code`
But points are drawn out of some views and not in every views, so I thought I didn't understand what that co-ordinates are.

Comment: @vilandra did you find a solution for this?